# Making changes to fragment in Asynctask's onPostExecute() method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am trying to hide progress bar and set an error message on an edit text in a  fragment from an `onPostExecute()` but my app keeps crashing. I need some help on how to correctly do this. I will be doing a lot of updates to my fragments for this project so I need to know the right way TO UPDATE A FRAGMENT FROM `OnPostExecute()` method.

I tried creating an object of the `Fragment` class and then using the object I tried to access the `EditText` and the progressBar method called `showProgress()` but I get run time error.

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String jsonStr = result;
        SellerRegisterFragment sr = new SellerRegisterFragment();
        Toast toast = null;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    toast = null;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Registered successfully. You can now Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (toast == null || toast.getView().getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SellerLoginOrRegisterActivity.class));
                }
                }
                else if (query_result.equals("DUPLICATE")) {
                    toast = null;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Account for the given URL already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sr.showProgress(false);
                }
                else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data."+"...... "+ jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can u post logcat?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...I will post it rightnow.. please wait 1 min

Comment: I get this error:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SellerRegisterFragment{1b16e429} not attached to Activity

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp, PID: 4652 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SellerRegisterFragment{1b16e429} not attached to Activity at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:639) at comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp.SellerRegisterFragment.showProgress(SellerRegisterFragment.java:182)  at comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp.SignupActivity.onPostExecute(SignupActivity.java:89)  at comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp.SignupActivity.onPostExecute(SignupActivity.java:21)

Comment: sr.editText.setError("Duplicate websites");  What is sr?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the Fragment instance inside onPostExecute. And then using the member variables of the Fragment. Just creating the instance of Fragment wont do anything.

You have to add the Fragment to a Activity. Only then the callbacks of the Fragment are executed. In those callbacks(like onCreate, onCreateView), you will be creating instances of the EditText, ProgressBar.

If you use those variables without adding the Fragment to the Activity, you will get NullPointerException.

What I guess is, you already added a Fragment to the Activity. Instead of using that Fragment instance, you are creating a new instance and using that instance inside onPostExecute.

Comment: yes fragment is already been added to the activity.. when user clicks on register button the asynctask does its job i.e. it validates the user on the server and until the onPostExecute() method is executed a progress bar is  shown on the fragment... i want to hide the progress bar on the fragment and set an error message on the fragment which is already been added to the activity

Comment: my question basically is .. how to make changes to fragment ui elements like textview, edit text, etc from onPostExecute() method from asynctask.

Comment: ok. pass the fragment instance to the AsyncTask through the constructor of AsyncTask. Save the instance inside the AsyncTask. Use that instance in the onPostExecute, instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: could you write a pseuodo or a demo code for it please!

Comment: sure. new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(); here this is fragment instance.

Comment: public void MyAsyncTask(MyFragment fragment){ this.fragment = fragment; }

Answer (score 0):

Your error log clearly states the problem.

```
Fragment SellerRegisterFragment{1b16e429} not attached to Activity
```

The problem is that you're trying to call the method on your SellerRegisterFragment before it gets attached to an Activity.

FragmentS are associated with activities and you can find the description in the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I have a doubt on your logic in the following LOC

```
SellerRegisterFragment sr = new SellerRegisterFragment();
```

Do you want to call a method on an existing instance of `SellerRegisterFragment`? If so, then you can easily use a `broadcast`.

If not, then you need to create a new instance, then use a `FragmentManager` to perform a `transaction` and then `commit` the `transaction`.